# data list validate options Only

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, sql

i want accept the selection values only. but currently if user type eg:"opra" and it accepts that value to my database. This is search Option Box

```
<input list="brow">
<data list id="brow">
  <option value="Internet Explorer">
  <option value="Firefox">
  <option value="Chrome">
  <option value="Opera">
  <option value="Safari">
</data list>
```

Comment: Please tell your problem more briefly

Comment: Make it a select instead of a data list. Then verify in php that the option is valid

Comment: Data List will act as recommended options but if you want to select only some values try to use the select tag

Comment: You should be **validating** the user's input before sending it to the database _anyhow_ -- no matter what element you are providing in your form.  Providing a client-side validation before or upon submission is more of a nicety, server-side validation is more of a requirement for keeping your data clean, stable, and secure.  Your list of options is not long, just use a `<select>`.  You are making this job harder than it needs to be.

Answer (score 0):

You could have validation logic when you are send the input value to the server, if the value isn't in the options you show an error label.

Answer (score 0):

In most databases, this would be handled with a `check` constraint:

```
alter table t check (browser in ( <valid values go here> ) )
```

Unfortunately, MySQL accepts the syntax for check constraints, but does not actually implement them.

That leaves you with four options:

1. In MySQL 8+, you can create a view using `with check option`.  This is probably the preferable method.
2. Maintain a list of acceptable values in a reference table.
3. Use an enumerated type.
4. Enforce the value using a trigger.

In earlier versions, the second method is possibly the best.  You can fetch the `browser_id` from the `browsers` table as a prelude to whatever you are doing.  If the `browser_id` does not exist, return an appropriate error.